# How to connect an LED indicator with a switch to this device?

Tags: led, switches, arc

I would like to know how can i add a safety switch with an LED indicator to the input of this device , so that if the safety switch is on then the LED lights , and when i want to use the device , all what i have to do is to press the normally-open switch.

I have attached this schematic and im not sure if it will work correctly ,as i am a very beginner in electronics, so is the design correct?

The device itself is an arc generator with a DC input and th following parameters (Input voltage: DC3.7-7.4V , Input Current: 2A-5A).

I know how to size the LED resistor but not too sure about the switch how can i size it please ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you need clarification, edit your old question,  don't post a new one.

Comment: ok sorry i wanted new answers with clarifications

Comment: define maximum transient voltage above R1 !! both +/- values.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you mean , i was going to use 7.4 for the battery ,, the LED takes away 2.something i guess , please make it easier for me to understand what you mean thanks

Answer (score 0):

The design you have looks reasonable.

The safety switch will need to be rated for at least whatever voltage and current are expected in your circuit. Based on the parameters you mentioned, that would be 7.4V (which won't be an issue) and 5A (which might be).

Comment: can i use an AC switch for this one

Answer (score 0):

One small thing to consider here is wetting current.  If you pick a switch with brass contacts they will oxidize fairly quickly.  Normally when a switch is closed there is an arch the will burn through the oxidation making a good contact.  If you use a 5A, plus a little for margin, switch it my not make contact when you close it with a 20mA load.  Of course you will know this because the led will no stay on.  You can solve this one of two ways.  One is to pick a switch that specifies a minimum load current less then the led current.  The other is to put a capacitor across the led and resistor.  The capacitor will draw a larger current to provide the wetting current.  When the switch is open it will discharge through the LED.